# Change a vlan number in file.txt

Tags: tcl

I need to change a vlan number 1 to 555 on a list like below:

file.txt

```
SW1#sh interfaces status

Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Fa0/1                        connected    trunk        full    100    10/100BaseTX
Fa0/2                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/3                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/4                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/5                        connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/6                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/7                        connected    1          a-half   a-10 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/8                        connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/9                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/10                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/11                       connected    1          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/12                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/13                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/14                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/15                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/16                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/17                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/18                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/19                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/20                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/21                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/22                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/23                       notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/24   TRUNK VOICE BRANCH  connected    100        a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Gi0/1                        connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/2                        notconnect   1            auto   auto Not Present
```

Code:

```
set f [open "file.txt" r]
  foreach a [split [read -nonewline $f] \n] {
    set 0 [lindex $a 0]
    set b [lsearch -inline -regexp $a "1"]

    if { [regexp {^F|^G|^P} $0] && $b == "1"} {   
      puts "conf t"
      puts "interface $0"
      puts "switchport access vlan 555"
    }
}


 Output:

 conf t
 interface Fa0/2
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/3
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/4
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/5
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/6
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/7
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/8
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/9
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/20
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/22
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Fa0/23
 switchport access vlan 555
 conf t
 interface Gi0/2
 switchport access vlan 555
```

How you can see, the ports Fa0/10 till Fa0/19 and the port Fa0/21 don't was configured. I try change the lsearch with other things, but till now I failed.

The correct output that I expect, is that all the ports with vlan 1 I need to  change to vlan 555. How I can do this?

Tkanks.

Comment: I believe your regexp search for "1" snags on the 1 on 10-19 and 21. Try using `{\m1\M}` instead.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Exaclty what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lsearch -inline -regexp $a "1"` finds any kind of string with a "one" digit in it, such as 19. Later, when this is compared to 1 in `$b == "1"`, this becomes `19 == 1`, which fails.

The solution is to constrain the match to the exact string `1`, by using one of several possible regexes: `{\m1\M}` is one, but `{\y1\y}` or `{^1$}` works too.

Mind you, this code is still somewhat brittle (the match on the first line, for instance, works by coincidence only).

`if {[string match {[FGP]*} $a] && [string range $a 42 52] == 1}` would probably be better.

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/_syntax.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

(See "Constraint escapes" in the regex syntax docs.)